# uniform quantizer for sine wave with amplitude -1 db

Tags: matlab

i have a signal sine wave with an amplitude of -1 db The quantizer step Δ is 1/7. The middle quantization level is 0 and the other levels are ±kΔ,, k=1-7. the output is 4-bit unsigned integer which values from 0 to 14 corresponding to the 15 quantization levels. how i can do this in matlab

Comment: -1dB with respect to WHAT?

Comment: what am asking is how to create a uniform quantizer that has 15 level , and 0 is the middle level and other levels is k*delta , with a step of  delta=1/7

Comment: You've just repeated what is in your question and haven't answered the comment.

Comment: - 1 db in amplitude it will be AM=10^(-1/20);
signal = AM*sin(2*pi*f*nT);

Comment: So. 0.89, right? What is that in LSB (quantizer steps)?

Comment: quantizer step is delta , the step from level to other

Answer (score 0):

With simulink, use the quantizer block: https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/quantizer.html

The same page describes the "matlab script" equivalent:

```
y = q * round(u/q)
where y is the quantized output, u is the input, and q is the Quantization interval.
```

This will provide an output in the same units as input. If you wish for the output to be a raw quantization count, just remove the multiplication by quantization interval.